# Plot with substitution of domain values before evaluation of function

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, replacement

I have a function of two variables $f(x,y)$. I find the maximum value of $f(x_0,y)$ by first substituting the value of $x=x_0$ and then maximizing in the range $0<y<1$.

My question is: How to `plot` a function with first substituting a value of $x=x_0$ and then getting out a value from`FindMaximum` for a range of values $1<x_0<2$?

MWE:

```
f[x_] := (x + y)^2;
Plot[FindMaximum[{f[x], 0 < y < 1}, y], {x, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999 for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_] := (x + y)^2;
obj[x_?NumericQ] := First@FindMaximum[{f[x], 0 < y < 1}, y];
Plot[obj[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Or you could use

```
obj[x_?NumericQ] := FindMaxValue[{f[x], 0 < y < 1}, y]
```

Comment: Thank you. What would be the obj function if my function has three variables? f(x0,y0,z)?

Comment: @kaka You're welcome. I suppose it would likely be `obj[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := f[x0, y0, z]`, but it could depend on the details of the function and its use.